# Java Database connetivity error

Tags: java, javadb

I am trying to connect `Java DB`. But when i start `java DB` it confirms that server is started

```
Mon Nov 11 03:15:45 PKT 2013 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Mon Nov 11 03:15:45 PKT 2013 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.8.3.0 - (1405108) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

but when i create a new database it takes too long time and after that generates error screen shot attatched of error.

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/j1ok3kx47/)

Comment: Sounds like you have a proxy between you and the db server and SOCKS is messing with that connection.

Comment: yeah, we use proxy to connect to internet but i dont where to put that proxy and port adress in this case. can you guide me to that??

Comment: I'd add localhost the proxy exclude list in IE/windows to start with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like...

A: you are trying to use NetBeans in-built database server. aka Derby.

B: When you right click and click "Start" you get the message

```
Mon Nov 11 03:15:45 PKT 2013 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Mon Nov 11 03:15:45 PKT 2013 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.8.3.0 - (1405108) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

So I presume the server is started ok.

C: You are then trying to create a new database on the Derby server, via right click and "create database"

[image]

I still think that the Proxy is the most likely cause of connection problem.
Do you have a Proxy configurated in the IDE Settings ? If so try it with 'No Proxy'.

Comment: Database created! i removed proxy from IDE setting i.e. set it to no Poxy and it worked. Thanks!